# Laravel Socialite Callback URL not approved for this client application

Tags: laravel, oauth, twitter-oauth, laravel-socialite

I tried to add Twitter OAuth to my Laravel App, I followed multiple tutorials but always had the same issue.

`Received HTTP status code [403] with message "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error code="415">Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings</error></errors>" when getting temporary credentials.`

In Twitter Developer Portal, I have Elevated access, which seems to be the one that is needed for this.

In my Laravel APP, I created a new fresh one for try this, I have this:

Twitter Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class TwitterController extends Controller
{
    public function handle() {
        return Socialite::driver('twitter')->redirect();
    }

    public function callbackHandle() {
        $user = Socialite::driver('twitter')->user();
        dd($user);
    }
}
```

I have also tried in callbackHandle() function:

```
public function callbackHandle() {
        $user = Socialite::driver('twitter')->userFromTokenAndSecret('API KEY', 'CLIENT SECRET');;
        dd($user);
    }
```

Also tried to put consumer keys in the step of client id and client secret, but both of them didn't work.

In config/services.php I have:

```
    'twitter' => [
        'client_id' => '',
        'client_secret' => '',
        'redirect' => 'miv.test/twitter/callback',
    ],
```

In client_id and client_secret, I also tried the consumer keys, but both of them didn't work.

web.php

```
Route::get('twitter', [TwitterController::class,'handle'])->name('twitter');
Route::get('twitter/callback', [TwitterController::class,'callbackHandle'])->name('twitter.callback');
```

In my Twitter Developer Page I have this:

[image: Twitter Developer Page]

So the thing is that I tried all that is on https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/socialite and when I try to follow any tutorial for any reason this error doesn't appear to them.

Comment: > 'redirect' => 'miv.test... why don't you make this `'redirect' => 'http://miv.test`

Comment: @UnderDog, the redirect must be a URL that is for a callback, all people in tutorials do something similar to what I have.